# removing backround image using next(); and prev(); in jquery from menu

Tags: jquery

i am trying to remove the background images from the `<a>`before and after `a.current`
So in the example below "the herbs" link wouldn't have one and neither would "fees".

```
<ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="the-herbs"><a href="#">The Herbs</a></li>
    <li class="blog current"><a class="current" href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="fees"><a href="#">Fees</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I've been trying to use jquery next and previous but not quite getting it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li.current a').parent.prev().css('background', 'none');

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `parent` is a method, so you need to write `parent()` and this should work assuming the background is on the `<li>`

Comment: Noted...sill typo!  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think that there is no 'parent' property on a jQuery object, there is function 'parent()' though. Also, you need to remove background from 'a', not from 'li', so it should be:

```
 $('li.current a').parent().prev().children('a').css('background', 'none');
```

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, parent() and then children is not needed here. Just `prev()` and `next()`.

Comment: Without 'children()' you will select next/previous 'li' element, not 'a'. I'm under impression, that author needed to remove background from 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `parent()`. From documentation of **prev**:

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

So, it should look like this:

```
$('li.current a').prev().css('background', 'none');
$('li.current a').next().css('background', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the `<li>`s immediately before and after the `.current` one, but specifying the wrong property. Try `backgroundImage` instead of `background` to remove the background image.